# jquery change absolute positioned parent height to child height

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out is there a way to get the height of the absolute positioned child and set it to parent with jQuery? For example the child has a hidden div and after clicking a radio button, the div will show and expand the height of the absolute positioned child.

```
<ol id="relative_one"> 
    <li> 
        <div class="tabbed_title"> 
            <div class="absolute_positioned child"></div> 
    </li> 
</ol>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "do it like ajax"? Ajax is used to send HTTP(S) requests to a server and load the server response data back into the script.

Comment: `<ol id="relative_one">
    <li>
        <div class="tabbed_title">
        <div class="absolute_positioned child"></div>
    </li>
</ol>`

Comment: Sorry for the term ajax-like but as I've said, whenever the absolute positioned child is change like a hidden div is shown, the parent div will get that height automatically without refreshing the page

Comment: The HTML you gave is invalid. Please edit the question using the HTML that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and set height using jQuery like this:

```
<!-- html from the comment from the original question -->
<ol id="relative_one">
    <li>
        <div class="tabbed_title">
        <div class="absolute_positioned child"></div>
    </li>
</ol>

var $child = $('.child');
var $parent = $('.tabbed_title');

$("#radioButton").change(function () {
    var childHeight = $child.height();
    $parent.height(childHeight);
});
```